# Posting PHP Variable on Link Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have a table that shows all online players on my game server and I have setup a script that can Slap, Kick, Mute them etc, I'm trying to use JS to have a dropdown memnu on the online players table that lets me Slap, kick, mute them etc but I dont know how to POST the $playerid variable to the script so that it slaps the player.

Here is my table
When slap kick or mute button is clicked I'd like it to POST the $playerid to the q3/slap.php file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lou3N.png

And here is my code

```js
function slap(){
  
    var playerid = $("#playerid").val();
  
    $.post("../q3/slap.php", { playerid: playerid }, function ( data ) {
    });
 return false;
}
```

```html
  echo "<td align=center> $team </td>";
  echo "<td align=center><a href='user.php?id=".$row["DBID"]."' > $name </a></td>";
  echo "<td align=center> $group </td>";
  echo "<td align=center> $score </td>";
  echo "<td align=center> $ip </td>";
  echo "<td align=center>";
  echo "<div class=dropdown>";
  echo "<button class=dropbtn>Dropdown</button>";
  echo "<div class=dropdown-content onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
  echo "<a id=myLink href=# onclick='slap();return false;'>Slap</a>";
  echo "<a id=myLink href=# onclick='kick();return false;'>Kick</a>";
  echo "<a id=myLink href=# onclick='mute();return false;'>Mute</a>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to include the playerid within the function call? i.e. onclick='slap({$playerid});return false;' BTW, id's are suppose to be unique so you <a id='myLink ... is invalid html

Comment: I tried onclick='slap({$playerid}) but it doesn't work? :S and the ID's I have now removed as I dont need them

Comment: What do you mean by 'id doesn't work'? Did you also change the function call to function slap(playerid) { $.post("../q3/slap.php", { playerid: playerid }, function ( data ) {  });  return false;}

Answer (score 0):

You must change your html code first. Don't use more to 1 time the same ID and pass the parameter with data-xxx attribute

You can do something like that :

HTML

```
<div class="action" data-id-player="<?php echo $playerid ?>">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="" data-action="slap">slap</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-action="kick">kick</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-action="mute">mute</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Your jQuery script :

```
$('.action').on('click', 'a',function(){
    var playerid    = $(this).parent().attr('data-id-player');
    var action      = $(this).attr('data-action');
    var url ='';

    switch(action) {
        case 'slap':
            url = 'slap.php';
        break;
        case 'kick':
            url = 'kick.php';
        break;
        case 'mute':
            url = 'mute.php';
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url : href,
    method: "POST",
    async : false,
    data: { your_data(the id of player)  }
    success : function(response){
          // Do somethings
    }
});
```

EDIT : Your code ...
You must separate the JS and the PHP in 2 files. I've not tested the code so make sure to correctly add him to your code.

```
        echo "<td align=center> $team </td>";
        echo "<td align=center><a href='user.php?id=".$row["DBID"]."' > $name </a></td>";
        echo "<td align=center> $group </td>";
        echo "<td align=center> $score </td>";
        echo "<td align=center> $ip </td>";
        echo "<td align=center>";
        echo "<div class=dropdown>";
        echo "<button class=dropbtn>Dropdown</button>";
        echo "<div class=dropdown-content onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
?>
        <div class="action" data-id-player="<?php echo $row["DBID"] ?>">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="" data-action="slap">slap</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-action="kick">kick</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-action="mute">mute</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
<?php

        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";


jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('.action').on('click', 'a',function(){
        var playerid    = $(this).parent().attr('data-id-player');
        var action      = $(this).attr('data-action');
        var url ='';

        switch(action) {
            case 'slap':
                url = 'slap.php';
            break;
            case 'kick':
                url = 'kick.php';
            break;
            case 'mute':
                url = 'mute.php';
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url : "../q3/"+action,
            method: "POST",
            async : false,
            data: { playerid: playerid)  },
            success : function(response){
                  // Do somethings
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

Comment: My jquery works, I just don't know how to get the link to post the information when the "slap" link is clicked

Comment: I've edited my response. I think the first step is correctly write your DOM :)

Comment: Sorry. I'm a noob with JS, which bits of this code do I need to edit? :P and thank you so much for your assistance

Comment: Edited. But now, try to understand and adapt the code to your need

Comment: Thank you again for the code, I've changed it to fit into my table and I click on the buttons nothing happens, Is there a way I can get errors to echo back to me so I can see why it's not working, thanks again.

Comment: If you use firefox, I suggest you install firebug plugin. In all case, you can see the ajax call in the console of your browers (chrome or firefox for example). On window, the touch is F12. Or right click and found "inspect element" or something like that